# Writing out a product of permutations as the product of disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $ \tau = (1~3)(2~4) $ and $ \sigma = (1~2~4~5) $

Is it correct to say that   (working from right to left) $ \sigma \tau = (1~3)(2~5) $ and $ \tau \sigma = (1~4)$ ?

Comment: depends on your country, "right to left" or "left to right"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "working from right to left"? $\sigma\tau$ always means "apply first $\tau$ and afterwards $\sigma$".

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth What do you mean "right to left" or "left to right". Cycles are functions defined on elements of $S_n$. There's only one way to apply them.

Comment: Just as Steven Van Geluwe mentions

Comment: @gebruiker "left to right" means that when $\sigma \tau$ is applied on cycle $2$, it is calculated as follows, $(2) \sigma \tau=(4) \tau =2$. English writers tends to write this way. One book I can recall is "Representations and Characters of Groups" by Martin Lieback in which function composition is treated left to right

Answer (score 1):

No, you are incorrect.

$\sigma \tau = (1,3,2,5)$ and

$ \tau \sigma= (1,4,5,3)$

Comment: Sorry I think I misstyped the question

Comment: I have editied.

Answer (score 0):

$\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$ if and only if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two disjoint cycles (which is not the case here).

My calculations resulted in  $\sigma\tau=(1\:3\:2\:5)$ and $\tau\sigma=(1\:4\:5\:3)$. Do yo need extra help with this?